# Shannon Entropy of a periodic signal

Tags: information-theory, entropy

We have a source $X$ with alphabet size equal to $N$. The Shannon entropy is defined as
$$E(X)=-\sum _{i=1}^{N}p_{i}\cdot\log _{2}p_{i}$$
where $p_i$ is the probability of symbol $i$ appearing in the stream of characters of the message.

If the source transmits $M>N$ symbols so that the resulting signal is periodic (i.e. it "completes a pattern within a measurable time frame, called a period and repeats that pattern over identical subsequent periods", from [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Signals_and_Systems/Periodic_Signals)) what is the entropy worth in this case?

Comment: $N$ is the alphabet size (how many available symbols there are to choose from at each time), or is the block length (related to the period?)

Comment: @leonbloy thanks, I edited my post

Comment: It should be $H(X)$ instead of $E(X)$. Also, I don't understand what relevance has $M>N$, and what relation (if any) has $M$ with the period.